# Show that every ideal of a ring R is the kernel of some ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

**Theorem** - Show that every ideal of a ring R is the kernel of some homomorphism R to some other ring.

**My proof**: Let A be an ideal of $R$

**Define**: $f : R \rightarrow R/A$

$f(r) = r + A , \forall r \in R$

**To show**: f is ring homom. (and well defined) and then to show $ker(f) = A$

$f$ **is well defined:** $x=y$ then $x + A = y + A$, then $f(x) = f(y)$.

$f(x+y) = (x+y) + A = (x + A) + (y + A) = f(x) + f(y)$

$f(xy) = (xy) + A = (x+A)(y+A) = f(x)f(y)$

**To show**: $ker(f) = A$

**Proof**: $kerf = \{x \in R | f(x) = 0 + A\} = \{x \in R | x + A = 0 + A\} = \{x \in R | x + A = A\} = \{ x \in R | x \in A \}$. Thus, $ker(f) = A$.

**My question:** *I'm not sure the proof is true*, does $f : R \rightarrow R/A$ generalizes to 'any ring homomorphism'?

Comment: You don't need to show well-definedness, since you're not making a "choice" at any point. Your proof works, but it's not clear what your question is. You just need to find at least one homomorphism such that $A$ is its kernel.

Comment: @lokodiz I'm not quite sure that I had to use the definition with the quotient ring (what I defined). Well if you agree that the proof is correct, everything is fine :)

Comment: Your proof that $f$ is a homomorphism whose kernel is $A$ is fine but technically, you have to show that the quotient is a ring. That's where you show that addition and multiplication are well defined. If you are allowed to use the result that the quotient is a ring then I'd say you are good.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if $A$ is an ideal, then it is the kernel of the morphism you gave.

On the other hand, the kernel of a ring homomorphism is an ideal.

I'm not sure the answer you expect for your question.